# MinGW32-GCC, LibCurl Linking Pro

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, libcurl, mingw32

I am having quite a problem compiling `LibCURL` with `MinGW32-gcc` on my pc. I put the files from the LibCURL download "includes", "lib", and "bin" into the corresponding MinGW32 folders. Currently my code is below and it is extremely simple for testing if it worked(Which it is not as I am posting here.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    /************************
            Variables
    ************************/

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    return 0;
}
```

Which I then in term compile with the following command line:

```
mingw32-gcc main.c -lcurl -o compiled.exe --std=c99
```

That compiler command line is throwing the following error:

```
C:\Users\Ikaros\AppData\Local\Temp\ccc5ojVE.o:main.c:(.text+0x8e): undefined ref
erence to `_imp__curl_global_init'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Do you have any recommendation on why this would not be working the way it should?

Comment: You said you downloaded LibCURL. Where did you get it from and how was it compiled? You've added something to the /lib & /bin directories that might not be correct for your architecture. That is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: I used the following link: "http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=lib&os=Win32&flav=-" I was using there guided download. There is only 1 download for LibCURL 32bit for Windows. Is this the wrong download?

Comment: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html has a listing of the available downloads and I see a "Win64 - MinGW64" section. That might be the right one but you listed MinGW32 above. You might need to compile LibCURL in you environment. But that definitely looks like a library/arch mismatch.

Comment: I will give that a try and post back in a couple of minutes! Thanks for the quick reply and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possibly a mismatch of the library to the local architecture ie. MinGW32 versus MinGW64. The download site for libCurl has a prebuilt library for MinGW64 but not MinGW32.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to link with a static lib on windows without compiling with the CURL_STATICLIB define set. As explained in [this libcurl FAQ entry](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Link_errors_when_building_libcur).